# "Class contains 1 abstract method so must be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (parent::hasErrors)"

Tags: php, interface, abstract-class

This is my code:

```
interface ValidatorInterface
{
  public function hasErrors ();
  public function validate (stdClass $metadata);
  public function getFeedback ();
}

abstract class ValidatorAbstract implements ValidatorInterface
{
  protected $feedback;

  public function __construct ()
  {
    $this->feedback = new FormFeedback();
  }


  public function getFeedback ()
  {
    return $this->feedback;
  }


  public function hasErrors ()
  {
    return $this->getFeedback()->hasErrors();
  }
}

class RegistrationValidator extends ValidatorAbstract
{
  public function validate (stdClass $metadata)
  {
    $this->getFeedback()->addError('Testing');

    return !!$this->hasErrors();
  }
}
```

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Class RegistrationValidator
>   contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or
>   implement the remaining methods
>   (ValidatorInterface::hasErrors)

The abstract class `ValidatorAbstract` satisfies the requirements imposed by `ValidatorInterface` to have the `hasErrors()` and `getFeedback()` methods.

The class `RegistrationValidator` extends `ValidatorAbstract` and satisfies the last remaining requirement to declare a `validate()` method.

Why then am I getting an error saying that `RegistrationValidator` contains an abstract method, when it doesn't, and that it must implement `hasErrors()` when that method is already implemented by its parent class?

Comment: Please supply a complete runnable example. I cannot reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the code you posted is the same as the one you are running. In the example you posted, every abstract method is implemented somewhere in the hierarchy and the code runs fine.

Also make sure the file you are editing is the running copy (it could be cached).

Comment: The live code was actually several files. `ValidatorAbstract.php` was the one that apparently was cached. Silly issue. It must have not successfully uploaded, since there's no OpCode cache on this server.

Comment: Simplest issues are often the hardest to find :(

Answer (score -2):

In abstract class you need to have at least one abstract method.

```
abstract protected function someFunction();
```

A good practice is not to put any code into abstract classes.

Comment: An abstract class is not required to have an abstract method. BTW `ValidatorAbstract` does not implement `ValidatorInterface::validate`, so it needs to be abstract.

Comment: I was totally convinced that is neccessary - thanks for your comment.

Comment: Nah. U could just use an abstract class only to be sure all the object are of the same basetype :)